# Докер может запускать приложения с графической оболочкой?

Tags: docker

Docker на котором установлен пакет [Rust](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust)-а может запускать программы с графическим интерфейсом без лишних настроек?

Comment: Может с «лишними настройками», но зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас вопрос "сильно неполный", но короткий ответ на него - "да"

А теперь углубимся в детали.

В том смысле, что Вы набираете что то вроде "docker run..." , и у Вас на экране волшебно возникает графический интерфейс программы-нет, такого не будет.

Придется сделать ещё один шаг: взять из "стартовавшего докера" ссылку, и скопировать ее либо в браузер, либо в xserver, либо ещё в какую то программу-в зависимости от того, что Вы понимаете под графическим интерфейсом.

И, ещё: вообще ещё есть такая штука-snap, может быть, она Вам больше подойдёт?

Comment: Как бы случайно не оказалось, что автор использует Windows, это добавит кучу веселья)

Comment: Ну, в смысле браузера, xserver-а и докера виндовс уже почти "как взрослая" :-)